# Use $group twice with in a single mongo query and $project result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below given are the three documents from my mongodb collection,

```
[
{
    "_id" : "58ad8a35ef2bf403cc4750ff1",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 1",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 1.1",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1.1.1"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "58ad8a35ef2bf403cc4750ff2",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 1",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 1.1",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1.1.2"
     }
},
{
    "_id" : "58ad8a35ef2bf403cc4750ff3",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 1",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 2",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1.2.1"
     }
}
]
```

> Note:

I have various Campaigns defined by "Campaign Name" field in my document, and then i have multiple Adsets(Ad Set Name) in each of the campaign, and then i have multiple ads(Ad Name) inside every adset(Ad Set Name) means every ad must belongs to one adset(Ad Set Name) and every adset(Ad Set Name) must belongs to a campaign(Campaign Name)

What I have done so far successfully:

```
db.adsets.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id:"$Data.Campaign Name",
            CampaignCount : {$sum:1},
            UniqueAdsets: {$addToSet : "$Data.Ad Set Name"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id:1,
            CampaignCount: 1,
            UniqueAdsets: 1,
            UniqueAdsetCount:{$size:"$UniqueAdsets"}
        }
    }
]);
```

I have already found out unique campaigns(Campaign Name) and adsets(Ad Set Name) against each of the unique campaign and their count, above query gives me this result,

```
[
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 1",
    "CampaignCount" : 60.0,
    "UniqueAdsets" : [ 
        "Adset 1", 
        "Adset 2", 
        "Adset 3", 
        "Adset 4"
    ],
    "UniqueAdsetCount" : 4
},
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 2",
    "CampaignCount" : 60.0,
    "UniqueAdsets" : [ 
        "Adset 1", 
        "Adset 2"
    ],
    "UniqueAdsetCount" : 2
}
]
```

I am trying to modify this query so it could given me Ads(Ad Name) and ads count inside every adset(Ad Set Name) that i found in my existing query.
I want something like this as an output,

```
[
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 1",
    "CampaignCount" : 60.0,
    "UniqueAdsets" : [ 
        {"Adset 1":["ad1","ad2","ad3"],"adcount":3}, 
        {"Adset 2":["ad1","ad2"],"adcount":2}, 
        {"Adset 3":["ad1","ad2"],"adcount":2}, 
        {"Adset 4":["ad1","ad2"],"adcount":2}
    ],
    "UniqueAdsetCount" : 4
},
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 2",
    "CampaignCount" : 60.0,
    "UniqueAdsets" : [ 
        {"Adset 2":["ad1","ad2"],"adcount":2}, 
        {"Adset 2":["ad1","ad2"],"adcount":2}
    ],
    "UniqueAdsetCount" : 2
}
]
```

I am trying this right now, but its not working,

```
db.adsets.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id:{"CampaignName":"$Data.Campaign Name"},
            CampaignCount : {$sum:1},
            UniqueAdsets: {$addToSet : "$Data.Ad Set Name"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id:{"AdsetName":"$Data.Ad Set Name"},
            UniqueAds: {$addToSet : "$Data.Ad Name"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id:0,
            CampaignName:"$_id.CampaignName",
            CampaignCount: 1,
            UniqueAdsets: 1,
            UniqueAdsetCount:{$size:"$UniqueAdsets"},
            UniqueAds:1,
            UniqueAds:{$size:"$UniqueAds"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: sample data which you have shared from your collection have same _id how is that possible

Comment: I forgot to change it while editing. Did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation.

`$group` : Group by `Campaign Name` to count the campaign and `$push` all the adsets into `Adsets` array.

`$unwind` : Unwind the `Adsets` array

`$group` : Group by `AdSetName` and `$push` all the adnames into `AdName` array and count the adsets.

`$group` : Final Group by `Campaign Name` to put everything back into desired response.

`$project` : Project all the desired fields and add the `$size` for adsets

```
db.adsets.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$Data.Campaign Name",
        CampaignCount: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        Adsets: {
            $push: {
                AdSetName: "$Data.Ad Set Name",
                AdName: "$Data.Ad Name"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Adsets"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Adsets.AdSetName",
        CampaignCount: {
            $first: "$CampaignCount"
        },
        CampaignName: {
            $first: "$_id"
        },
        AdsetCount: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        AdName: {
            $push: "$Adsets.AdName"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$CampaignName",
        CampaignCount: {
            $first: "$CampaignCount"
        },
        AdSets: {
            $push: {
                AdSetName: "$_id",
                AdName: "$AdName",
                AdsetCount: "$AdsetCount"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        CampaignCount: 1,
        AdSets: 1,
        AdsetCount: {
            $size: "$AdSets"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: That's incredible Veeram, how you did it. It has been more than 45mins since i posted this question and you were the last hope. Thanks alotttt. I am trying to understand the logic behind your answer. Its seems working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You are welcome. May be there are others ways of doing, but this is something that came to mind first. Added some description. Let me know if  you don't understand something.

Comment: Yes i have few questions, 
first one is, why are we using CampaignCount: {
            $first: "$CampaignCount"
        },
        CampaignName: {
            $first: "$_id"
        }, in second grouping stage?

Comment: So in each `$group` stage you've to keep all the fields you want it as part of final response. `$unwind` flattens the documents from last group. So you'll have something like `compaign1, adset1`, `compaign1, adset2` after unwinding and in the second group you pick the first compaign name as they are all same for that adset group to keep it in the pipeline.

Comment: If two campaigns used same adsets, won't you lose one campaign in second grouping. 
Consider data after unwind: campaign1-adSet1-ad1, campaign2-adSet1-ad2. When grouping using adset 1, campaign 2 will be lost. 
I do not know if such data is possible, it really depend on the question if ad array should contain ads applicable for that campaign only or OK to have ads from all across within a Campaign for a set. Grouping may have to be done within a given campaign/given set depending on that.

Comment: @Soorjith  I agree. That's a good observation. I just looked at the adset data and seems they are unique across documents.

Comment: @Soorjith: Is it because we are using $first: "$_id", it would only take a campaign name from the first stage of grouping, so the other one would be lost? Though it is not the case in my scenario, but its a good argument.

Comment: It's the grouping on `adsetname`. So you can have `adsets` mixed up there as you're looking at all the compaigns and ofcourse the `$first` won't work as expected.

Comment: @Abdul Moiz - Yes, in grouping on adsetname, $first will give only one of the compaign names(first one) if there are multiple campaign name for a given ad set name.

Answer (score 1):

An approach where grouping is done in order BY CampaignName, AdSet

`$group`: Grouping by Campaign Name and AdSet, select the count of ads applicable for this combination to be used for total campaign 
`$group`: Second one groups by campaign name only, prepares the set with adds array. Uses the count from previous selection for total count for campaign 
`$project`: Project required elements with set count as well

```
db.adsets.aggregate([ {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            "campaignName" : "$Data.Campaign Name",
            "adSet" : "$Data.Ad Set Name",
        },
        ads : {
            $addToSet : "$Data.Ad Name"
        },
        campaignSetAdCount : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id.campaignName",
        sets : {
            $addToSet : {
                adSet : "$_id.adSet",
                ads : "$ads",
                adCount : "$campaignSetAdCount",
                uniqueAdCount : {
                    $size : "$ads"
                }
            }
        },
        campaginCount : {
            $sum : "$campaignSetAdCount"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        campaignName : "$_id",
        campaginCount : 1,
        uniqueSetCount : {
            $size : "$sets"
        },
        sets : "$sets"
    }
} ])
```

Comment: This is an awesome approach too. It working perfectly fine too. Thanks alot.