# Using multiple $lookup with aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collections,

1. _project - It contains all the projects
2. _build - It contains all the builds and every build must belong to a project
3. _build.details - It contains ads which must belong to an adset and each adset must belongs to a campaign and each campaign must belongs to a build.

_project document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d8c501be2bee2bc0b3b081"),
    "CreatedBy" : ObjectId("58c801c606f72508d87421c6"),
    ....
    ....
},...
```

_build document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ee6c5e06f7254454a554fe"),
    "ModifiedBy" : ObjectId("58d93a98c6e7dbe94582619a"),
    "CreatedBy" : ObjectId("58d93a98c6e7dbe94582619a"),
    "ProgramId" : ObjectId("58c801b706f72508d87421c4"),
    "ProjectId" : ObjectId("58d9411ebe2bee43ec22aff6"),
    ....
    ....
},...
```

_build.detials document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de834cc6e7dbe945acf890"),
    "BuildId" : ObjectId("58ef4b95c6e7dbe945ba700b"),
    "Values" : null,
    "Headers" : null,
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Remarketing | Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 03-01-2017",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%-Cancelled Orders_Less than 50% | Desktop | Feed | Female | 21-65",
        "Ad Name" : "Carousel | Draw1,Excited2,Lottery5,Beach4 | S:1814082498827964 | 03-01-2017 | 70Custom Audiences | ",
        "Ad Set Run Status" : "ACTIVE",
        "Ad Status" : "ACTIVE",
        "Campaign Objective" : "Conversions",
        "Gender" : "Female",
        "Age Min" : "21",
        "Age Max" : "65",

    },
    "Status" : false,
    "CampaignName" : "Remarketing | Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 03-01-2017",
    "AdSetName" : "Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%-Cancelled Orders_Less than 50% | Desktop | Feed | Female | 21-65",
    "AdName" : "Carousel | Draw1,Excited2,Lottery5,Beach4 | S:1814082498827964 | 03-01-2017 | 70Custom Audiences | ",
    "Campaign_Status" : 1,
    "Campaign_Id" : "1",
    "Adset_Status" : 1,
    "Adset_Id" : "123",
    "Ad_Status" : 1,
    "Ad_Id" : "1234"
},...
```

What i want in my query:

I want to get all projects from _project collection and want builds against each of the project and then i want ads, adsets and campaigns and their count against each of the project and build combination.

Want output something like:

```
{
    "ProjectId" : ObjectId("58d8c501be2bee2bc0b3b081"),
    "BuildId" : ObjectId("5a5ads501basdadsc0b3b346"),
    "uniqueAdsCount" : "25",
    "uniqueAdsetCount" : "5",
    "uniqueCampaignCount" : "2",
    "uniqueAdNames":[

     ],
    "uniqueAdSetNames":[

     ],
    "uniqueCampaignNames":[

     ]
},
{
next project
},
{
next project
}...
```

What i have done so far:

```
db.getCollection('_build').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "_project",
            localField: "ProjectId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "result"
        }
   },
   {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            BuildId: "$_id",
            ProjectId: "$result._id"
       }
   },
   {
        $lookup:{
            from: "_build.detail",
            localField: "BuildId",
            foreignField: "BuildId",
            as: "resultS2"
        }
   },
   {
        $project:{
            BuildId: "$BuildId",
            ProjectId: "$ProjectId",
            adsCount: {$size: "$resultS2.AdName"},
            adSetCount: {$size: "$resultS2.AdSetName"},
            campaignCount: {$size: "$resultS2.CampaignName"},
        }
   }
]);
```

I have tried adding a group stage and use $addToSet but its giving me duplicates in adsets, i don't know what i am doing wrong:

```
db.getCollection('_build').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "_project",
            localField: "ProjectId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "result"
        }
   },
   {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            BuildId: "$_id",
            ProjectId: "$result._id"
       }
   },
   {
        $lookup:{
            from: "_build.detail",
            localField: "BuildId",
            foreignField: "BuildId",
            as: "resultS2"
        }
   },
   {
        $project:{
            BuildId: "$BuildId",
            ProjectId: "$ProjectId",
            adsCount: {$size: "$resultS2"},
            ads: "$resultS2"
        }
   },
   {
        $group:{
            _id: "$BuildId",
            UniqueAds: {$addToSet: "$ads.Data.Ad Name"},
            UniqueAdsets: {$addToSet : "$ads.Data.Ad Set Name"}
        }
   }
]);
```

Please help, and let me know in case of any queries, may be i am using a entirely wrong approach, i am new to mongodb.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just curious. Isn`t this problem same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418336/use-group-twice-with-in-a-single-mongo-query-and-project-result except you are storing the data now in joined collection ?

Comment: Yes its the same problem, but data model is very different this time, i have projects and builds and inside that i have ads, adsets and campaigns and i don't have ProjectId in _build.details collection, but i want all stats on the basis of project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation.

You `$group`, get `distinct` name values at  each level followed by `$size` in the `$addFields`.

```
  db.getCollection('_project').aggregate([
     {$lookup:{from: "_build",localField: "_id",foreignField: "ProjectId",as:"result"}},
     {$unwind:"$result"},
     {$project:{_id:0,ProjectId:"$_id",BuildId:"$result._id"}},
     {$lookup:{from:"_build.detail",localField:"BuildId",foreignField:"BuildId",as:"resultS2"}},
     {$unwind:"$resultS2"},
     {$group:{
    _id:{ProjectId:"$ProjectId", BuildId:"$BuildId",campaignName:"$resultS2.Data.Campaign Name",adSet:"$resultS2.Data.Ad Set Name"},
    uniqueAdNames:{$addToSet:"$resultS2.Data.Ad Name"}
        }
     },
     {$addFields:{uniqueAdsCount:{$size:"$uniqueAdNames" }}},
     {$group :{
     _id:{ProjectId:"$_id.ProjectId",BuildId:"$_id.BuildId",campaignName:"$_id.campaignName"},
     uniqueAdNames:{$first:"$uniqueAdNames"},
     uniqueAdsCount:{$first:"$uniqueAdsCount"},
     uniqueAdSets:{$addToSet:"$_id.adSet"}
        }
     },
     {$addFields:{uniqueAdsetCount:{$size:"$uniqueAdSets"}}},
     {$group:{
     _id:{ProjectId:"$_id.ProjectId",BuildId:"$_id.BuildId"},
     uniqueAdNames:{$first:"$uniqueAdNames"},
     uniqueAdsCount:{$first:"$uniqueAdsCount"},
     uniqueAdSetNames:{$first:"$uniqueAdSets"},
     uniqueAdsetCount:{$first:"$uniqueAdsetCount"},
     uniqueCampaignNames:{$addToSet:"$_id.campaignName"}
        }
     },
     {$addFields:{uniqueCampaignCount:{$size : "$uniqueCampaignNames"}}}
  ])
```

Comment: This is awesome. Well this look to big, but now i am able to atleast understand the logic behind your answers. Thanks alot.

Comment: You are welcome. Its just `$addToSet`, `$first` to keep old values & `$size` operators for each level in `$group + $project`. You can simplify it if you on 3.4 version by using `$addFields`.

Comment: I am trying to prepare another query my self using your previous answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418336/use-group-twice-with-in-a-single-mongo-query-and-project-result, i want to share it here and would like if you look into it and tell me if my approach is right or wrong.

Comment: Yes i am using 3.4

Comment: You should probably ask a new question or use the old one at least if you don`t mind. I've added 3.4 edits.