# Group using $group on a foreignField from another collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('_build').aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$ProjectId",
            Builds: {$addToSet: "$_id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "_build.detail",
            localField: "Builds",
            foreignField: "BuildId",
            as: "result"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id:0,
            ProjectId: "$_id",
            Builds: 1,
            BuildCountForProject: {$size: "$Builds"}
        }
    }

]);
```

Result of query:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "Builds" : [ 
        ObjectId("58f908411f19cf1d340974c2"), 
        ObjectId("58f902bd1f19cf1d3409749d")
    ],
    "ProjectId" : ObjectId("58f7a38f1f19cf38306a1b9c"),
    "BuildCountForProject" : 11
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Builds" : [ 
        ObjectId("58f797631091c228bc3af071"), 
        ObjectId("58f79fa31091c528bc4ff8f1"), 
        ObjectId("58f769441f19cf22dc92da24"), 
        ObjectId("58f633801f19cf4f8073b203")
    ],
    "ProjectId" : ObjectId("58e27c921091c22e34243db7"),
    "BuildCountForProject" : 4
}
```

I am getting Builds array against each of the project in my query result, i want to query another collection(using the same query) on the basis of Builds in each of the project, want to aggregate some data(Data must be grouped by ProjectId, I don't have ProjectId in the collection i want to join, but i have it in pipeline as you can see in result).

Example:

I want find the distinct count of Ads, Adsets, Campaign for these build,

1. ObjectId("58f908411f19cf1d340974c2")
2. ObjectId("58f902bd1f19cf1d3409749d")

Both of these builds belongs to project ObjectId("58f7a38f1f19cf38306a1b9c") as seen in result.

Want output like,

```
{
    "ProjetId" : ObjectId("58f7a38f1f19cf38306a1b9c"),
    "BuildId" :[ ObjectId("58f908411f19cf1d340974c2"), 
                ObjectId("58f902bd1f19cf1d3409749d")]
    "UniqueAdsCount" : 10,
    "UniqueAdsetCount": 5,
    "UniqueCampaignCount": 2 
},
{
    next ProjectId,
    Builds array,
    UniqueAdsCount
    UniqueAdsetCount
    UniqueCampaignCount
},...
```

Collection i want to join with_build.detials:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de834cc6e7dbe945acf890"),
    "BuildId" : ObjectId("58ef4b95c6e7dbe945ba700b"),
    "Values" : null,
    "Headers" : null,
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Remarketing | Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 03-01-2017",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%-Cancelled Orders_Less than 50% | Desktop | Feed | Female | 21-65",
        "Ad Name" : "Carousel | Draw1,Excited2,Lottery5,Beach4 | S:1814082498827964 | 03-01-2017 | 70Custom Audiences | ",
        "Ad Set Run Status" : "ACTIVE",
        "Ad Status" : "ACTIVE",
        "Campaign Objective" : "Conversions",
        "Gender" : "Female",
        "Age Min" : "21",
        "Age Max" : "65",

    },
    "Status" : false,
    "CampaignName" : "Remarketing | Remarketing | Facebook | Conversions | 03-01-2017",
    "AdSetName" : "Cancelled Orders_Greater than 50%-Cancelled Orders_Less than 50% | Desktop | Feed | Female | 21-65",
    "AdName" : "Carousel | Draw1,Excited2,Lottery5,Beach4 | S:1814082498827964 | 03-01-2017 | 70Custom Audiences | ",
    "Campaign_Status" : 1,
    "Campaign_Id" : "1",
    "Adset_Status" : 1,
    "Adset_Id" : "123",
    "Ad_Status" : 1,
    "Ad_Id" : "1234"
},...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query. Its similar to the query we've here [Using multiple $lookup with aggregation in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636918/using-multiple-lookup-with-aggregation-in-mongodb).

The below query will `$lookup` into `build details` to get all the fields and `$group` them one at a time for distinct values followed by `$project` to count the distinct values for each build.

The final `$group` is to push all the `builds` into an array while summing all the build details distinct counts.

```
   aggregate([
      { $group: {_id: "$ProjectId",Builds: {$addToSet: "$_id"}}},
      { $lookup: {from: "_build.detail",localField: "Builds",foreignField: "BuildId",as: "result"}},
      { $unwind: "$result"},
      {
        $group: 
         {
           _id: 
            {
              ProjectId: "$_id",
              BuildId: "$result.BuildId",
              campaignName: "$result.Data.Campaign Name",
              adSet: "$result.Data.Ad Set Name"
            },
            uniqueAdNames: {$addToSet: "$result.Data.Ad Name"}
          }
      },
      { $addFields: {uniqueAdsCount: {$size: "$uniqueAdNames"}}},
      {
        $group: 
          {
            _id: 
              {
                ProjectId: "$_id.ProjectId",
                BuildId: "$_id.BuildId",
                campaignName: "$_id.campaignName"
              },
              uniqueAdsCount: {$first: "$uniqueAdsCount"},
              uniqueAdSets: {$addToSet: "$_id.adSet"}
          }
      },
      { $addFields: {uniqueAdsetCount: {$size: "$uniqueAdSets"}}},
      {
        $group: 
          {
            _id:{ProjectId: "$_id.ProjectId", BuildId: "$_id.BuildId"},
            uniqueAdsCount: {$first: "$uniqueAdsCount"},
            uniqueAdsetCount: {$first: "$uniqueAdsetCount"},
            uniqueCampaignNames: {$addToSet: "$_id.campaignName"}
          }
      },
      { $addFields: {uniqueCampaignCount: {$size: "$uniqueCampaignCount"}}},
      {
        $group: 
         {
           _id: "$projectId",
           Builds: {$push: "$_id.BuildId"},
           uniqueAdsCount: {$sum: "$uniqueAdsCount"},
           uniqueAdsetCount: {$sum: "$uniqueAdsetCount"},
           uniqueCampaignCount: {$sum: "$uniqueCampaignCount"}
          }
      },
      {
        $project:
         {
           _id: 0,
           ProjectId: "$_id.ProjectId",
           Builds: 1,
           BuildCountForProject: {$size: "$Builds"},
           uniqueAdsCount: 1,
           uniqueAdsetCount: 1,
           uniqueCampaignCount: 1,
         }
      }
   ])
```

Comment: Thanks veeram, finally this was something i was looking for. This is great logic how you grouped parent elements in each stage and found count of 1 child at a time and then keep on carrying them to the last stage using $first. This is simply awesome.